# Normal AZW converters doesnt work. Amazon's AZW format book to PDF

Tags: converters, kindle

I have a amazon kindle book (.azw format) in my kindle app of my windows system. Normal AZW to pdf converters doesnt take this format. Can I convert azw to PDF?